# Email.php doesn't send all information to email

Tags: php, email

This has been keeping me crazy for three days. I can't figure out why the subject and comment does not send. I receive the email but no subject and comment. Everything else I do get.

Does anyone have any idea on what's going on here? This code worked on another site.

```
  <?php
   /* Set e-mail recipient */
   $myemail  = "myemail@outlook.com";
   $email_subject = "DO NOT REPLY";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
   $yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
   $subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
   $email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
   $website  = check_input($_POST['website']);
   $phone   = check_input($_POST['phone']);
   $how_find = check_input($_POST['how']);
   $comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");

   /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
   if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
   {
   show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a valid <strong>e-mail-address</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* If URL is not valid set show error message */
   if (!preg_match("%^((https?://>/>/)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i", $website))
   {
    show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a valid <strong>website address</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* If Name is not valid show error message */
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\\-\\., \']+$/", $yourname)) 
   { 
        show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a valid <strong>name</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* If Phone is not valid show error message */   
   if (!preg_match("/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\(\.\-\s]?([\d]{3})[\)\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/", $phone)) 
   { 
        show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a valid <strong>phone number</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* If subject is empty show error message */ 
   if($subject = "") 
   { 
        show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a <strong>subject</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* If message is empty show error message */ 
   if($comments = "") 
   { 
         show_error("<font color=#cc3333>Please enter a <strong>message</strong>.\n<br /></font>");
   }

   /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
   $message = " 

   Name: $yourname
   Email: $email
   Phone: $phone
   URL: $website

   How did he/she find us? $how_find

   Subject: $subject
   Comments: $comments

   ";

   // create email headers
   $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n".
   'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   /* Send the message using mail() function */
   mail($myemail, $email_subject, $message, $headers);

   /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
   header('Location: /thankyou.php');
   exit();

  /* Functions we used */
   function check_input($data, $problem='')
  {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
  {
     show_error($problem);
  }
      return $data;
  }

  function show_error($myError)
  {
   ?>
    <html>
    <body>

       <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
       <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
 <?php
    exit();
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: If you say "worked on another site", I did not look at your code, but I came along an ISP, that had critical things to set, before the e-mail gets sent at all. So perhaps you ask them?!?

Comment: replacing the use of `font` with css will not make it work, but is a good idea

Comment: I hate answering my own question but, as always, I figure it out the minute I ask for help. Anyway, here it is in case someone else has an issue like mine

I had if($subject = "")

when it should've been

if($subject == "")

I can't answer my own question, so if anyone of would like to answer it with my comment so that future visitors can see the answer, I'll appreciate it